# Cosine fitting with discrete values from a set of points

Tags: spectroscopy

I am trying to fit a cosine function with a least square method. The function looks something like:

\begin{equation}
A(K)=cos(2 K x)
\end{equation}
being $K=0,1....N$, and x a arbitrary number, so that I get a set of points A(K) and I am trying to find x. However for large enougth x, as the data points are limited, you may obtain a wrong result because of the $2\pi$ uncertainty. So I am wondering what it is the maximum value of x you can resolve correctly?

Comment: This sounds a bit like discrete Fourier analysis, but then it doesn't... have you tried looking at that - and at the closely related Nyquist criterion that tells you something about the relationship between sampling frequency and highest resolved frequency in a signal? This looks related. Perhaps you can describe your problem statement better (in terms of physics) - otherwise you may find that the digital signal processing SE site is a better match for your question.

Comment: Yes, the Nyquist criterion, that was what I was looking for, thank you!